# Creating words out of numbers from a file

Tags: python, txt

Right so, I have a file with lots of numbers in it. It is a .txt file with binary numbers in it so it has 0's, 1's and spaces every 8 numbers (it is the lyrics to Telegraph Road but in binary, but that isn't important). What I am trying to do is create a program that takes the file, reads a single character of the file, and depending on what it reads it then writes either "one" or "zero" in a second .txt file.

As it stands, as a proof of concept, this works:

```
with open('binary.txt') as file:
        while 1:
            string = file.read(1)
            if string == "1":
                print("one")
            elif  string == "0":
                print("zero")
```

It prints out either a "one" or "zero" in about 15000 lines:

[Picture of the IDLE Shell after running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEPcI.png)

In the future I want it to print them in set of eight (so that one line = one binary ascii code) but this is pointless if I cant get it to do the following first.

The following is instead of printing it to the IDLE, I want to write it into a new .txt file. A few hours of searching, testing and outright guessing has me here:

```
with open('binary.txt') as file:
    with open('words.txt') as paper:
        while 1:
            string = file.read(1)
            if string == "1":
                line = ['one']
                paper.writelines(line)
            elif  string == "0":
                line = ['zero']
                paper.writelines(line)
```

This then prints to the IDLE:

> paper.writelines(line),
> io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

It goes without saying that I'm not very good at this. it has been a long time since I tried programming and I wasn't very good at it then either so any help I will be much appreciative of.

Cheers.

Comment: `open('words.txt','w')` you have to open the file in write mode.  The default if not specified is read.  Run `help(open)` in Python to see the help for `open` where this is explained.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're calling `writelines()` instead of just `write()`?

Comment: you really want to see in your file something like `[1]` or just a number ?

Comment: Can you post a sample or the complete `binary.txt` file? You said the information are grouped in words composed of `0` and `1`, with `8` digits each, separated by space. I'm looking to see if there are newlines or any other control characters embedded in the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

So in python when you use `open()` function it opens the file in read mode, but you change this by passing a second argument specifying the permissions you need. For your need and to keep things simple you need to open the file in write mode or append mode.

```py
# this will clear all the contents of the file and put the cursor and the beginning
with open('file.txt') as f:
  # logic
```

```py
# this will open the file and put the cursor at the end of file after its contents
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
  # logic
```

Answer (score 0):

i think thats what you are trying to do

```
with open('binary.txt',"r") as file:
    with open('words.txt',"r+") as paper:
        while 1:
            for i in range(8):
                string = file.read(1)
                if string == "1":
                    line = 'one '
                    paper.write(line)
                elif  string == "0":
                    line = 'zero '
                    paper.write(line)
            paper.write("\n")
```

this program will take the binary file items.. and put them in the paper file as you said (1=one and 0=zero. 8 for every line)

Comment: This does seemed to have worked, although there are 4,014,819 lines to the text file (mostly of empty returns, last line with words was 2230) and many of the lines have only 6 or 7 words. I shall work on this until I get a solution.

Comment: Changing 8 to 9 has corrected the contents per line issue. Am yet to find something to fix the issue of creating empty lines after it has finished writing them out.

Comment: add new line manually `\n` string

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
with open('binary.txt',"r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    characters = data.split()
    print(len(characters))
    file.close()
with open('binary.txt',"r") as file:
    with open('words.txt',"w") as paper:
        count = 0
        while count < len(characters):
            for i in range(9):
                string = file.read(1)
                if string == "1":
                    line = 'one '
                    paper.write(line)
                    print("one")
                elif  string == "0":
                    line = 'zero '
                    paper.write(line)
                    print("zero")
            paper.write("\n")
            count += 1
```

Its probably really inefficient in places but it does the job.

Important stuff:

1. By not having the written file opened for writing but as default (reading), the program was unable to write to it. Adding `"w"` solved this, and also added an `"r"` onto the reading file to be safe.
2. Opening the read file once before to work out number of lines so that the program would stop churning out returns and making the write file millions of lines long if you didn't stop it immediately.

Worked out the number of lines necessary (the `(print(len(characters))` line is, ironically, unnecessary):

```
data = file.read()
    characters = data.split()
    print(len(characters))
```

Limited the number of lines the program could write by first setting a variable to 0, then changed the while loop so that it would continue looping if the variable has a number less than that of how many lines there are and then adding a bit of code to add 1 to the variable after every new line is made:

```
count = 0
```

```
while count < len(characters):
```

```
count += 1
```

3. `for i in range(8)` was changed to `for i in range(9)` so that it would actually produce words in blocks of 8 before making new lines. Before it would make a line of 8 and then a line of 7 every time until the last line, where it would only right the leftover words, which in my case was 6
4. Read file must have a very specific layout, that is only 0's and 1's, must have a space every 8 numbers and no returns at all:
   [Picture of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gcfN.png), notice how each "line" continues beyond the boundary, this is because each line is 1001 columns long but due to there being a limit per column of 1001, it returns back around to create a new line, while still counting as the same column on the counter at the bottom.